# Swap columns and rows in Power BI

Tags: pivot-table, powerbi-desktop

I am new in Power BI and want to test what things you can and can't do with it. So I tried to swap the columns and rows from the left table, to get a second table equal to the right one:
[image]

I found that you can turn rows into columns with pivot but the option in Power BI only allow me to pivot based in ONE column, not two:

[image]

I also found about DAX syntax, which is more flexible. I tried to use it to make a clone of the table. After studying a little bit, I made and run the next sentence:

```
NewTable = Var Table2 = DataTable( "Year", STRING,{  {"2020 Price"},{"2021 Price"}  }  ) 
Var CrossJoined = CROSSJOIN(Table1,Table2)
                
Return    SELECTCOLUMNS( CrossJoined , 
        "ID" , [ID] , 
        "Year" , [Year] , 
        "New York" , CALCULATE(SWITCH([Year] , 
            "2020" , [2020 Price] ,
            "2021" , [2021 Price] ,
            BLANK()); Table1[City] IN {"New York"}) ,
        "Chicago" , CALCULATE(SWITCH([Year] , 
            "2020" , [2020 Price] ,
            "2021" , [2021 Price] ,
            BLANK()); Table1[City] IN {"Chicago"})
            )
```

This doesn't work anyway. So, how can I swap correctly the rows and columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Power Query:

1. Select *2020 Price* and *2021 Price* columns and `Unpivot Columns`
2. Select *City* column and `Pivot Columns` based on *Value* column (Don't Aggregate)
3. `Remove` " Price" from *Attribute* column
4. `Rename` *Attribute* column
5. `Sort`/`Reorder` as desired